# App Passwords Sync between devices

Tags: applications, sync, google, browser, password

On an Android device, if we sign up on any app, the password gets automatically stored on the Google Account. With this, we can use Google Chrome to access the saved password on Desktop too. Can we do this with other browsers too, like Microsoft Edge or Firefox, if we install it on both, the Android device and the Desktop ?

Comment: Firefox has it's own sync service with an Google-independent account ([Firefox Sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/accounts/)). If you enter your Firefox account credentials on Android and Windows/Linux you can also sync your settings and passwords.

Comment: no i meant individual app passwords, like if i log into Instagram, the password somehow gets synced with the Desktop version of Google Chrome. So I'm asking, how to make it work with other browsers too @Robert

Comment: You are misinterpreting the functionality. There is no synchronization of apps between your Android and your desktop. Only the web browser Chrome syncs it's data between the two platform because you are logged in in both with the same Google account. The same works for some other web browsers but this is totally independent of Android.